# Google Cloud Using OAUTH 2.0

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

So..
i am trying to use an gmail api for test issues
and i stack on how to do the OAUTH 2.0 thing
this is the response now:

> Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

I visit [Google cloud console](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) and I create one but when i try to use it it didn't work it seems i did something wrong while creating it .

Can Any One Help in debugging this?

this is a snippet of the code

```
 const email_id = await fetch(
    "https://content-gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/the_destaionation%email.com/messages?includeSpamTrash=true&q=from%3some%email.com%20&maxResults=1&key=___key___",
    {
      headers: {
        "x-origin": "https://explorer.apis.google.com",

        authorization:
          "Bearer this is the key i want to generate and i don't know how",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      return data.messages[0].id;
    });
```

Comment: can you post [example] please

Comment: @DaImTo i did you can check now

Answer (score 0):

Creating a access token using the credentials that you have created is a several step process.[Server sided web apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)  Rather than coding this all manual i recommend following googles [quick start for the gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    userId: 'me',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const labels = res.data.labels;
    if (labels.length) {
      console.log('Labels:');
      labels.forEach((label) => {
        console.log(`- ${label.name}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No labels found.');
    }
  });
}
```